# How to restrict dirty data insertion in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table e.g `ItemGroup` and it has two columns e.g `ItemID`, `ItemGroupID`.

So while inserting into this table (already made proc I can not change), there is no constraint to avoid the dirty data insertion.

Right data:

```
ItemID     ItemGroupID
1          10
2          11
```

Wrong data

```
ItemID     ItemGroupID
1          10
1          11
2          11
```

Entry with the value 1 and 11 is wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by dirty data?

Comment: You need to explain ***why*** the row with (1, 11) is *wrong* by your definition .....

Comment: you mean Foreign Key??

Comment: You need to add unique key for ItemID and and ItemGroupID.

Comment: why the row with(1,11) is wrong --actually that is our internal logic that if an item is entered with any itemGroupID then that item should not come again with the another itemGroupID

Answer (score 3):

First remove wrong data from table and then execute below script, once you execute below script, table will not allow such wrong data.

```
  ALTER TABLE ItemGroup
  ADd UNIQUE un_const(ItemID, ItemGroupID);
```

Answer (score 0):

create one master table with compound (two column) primary key and create compound foreign key in ItemGroup table ON ItemID, ItemGroupID and reference it with the compound primary key.